# Implementing a Hill-Type Muscle Model

Tags: nonlinear-equations, computational-biology

I'm interested in implementing the muscle model used in [Geijtenbeek](http://www.goatstream.com/research/thesis/index.html) and [Wang et al's](http://graphics.stanford.edu/projects/bio-locomotion/) work.

Both papers link to the paper by [Geyer and Herr](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~hgeyer/Publications/Geyer&Herr-ReflexModel2Column.pdf), which describes this model:

[image: Geyer and Herr muscle model]

However, the paper on this model assumes you already know how to model a Hill-Type muscle, and are simply augmenting it and placing many copies of it together in a biologically accurate way.

So in trying to learn how to implement the model itself, I found [Gribble's Tutorial](http://www.gribblelab.org/compneuro/) which was informative, but a very simplified model of what is used in practice.

I also found [Prochazka et al's](http://jn.physiology.org/content/77/6/3237) paper, which seems to be the best detailed reference on implementation, however it describes it in the context of a visual language for describing dynamic systems (Simulink). So I have been learning simulink to do this, but once I reproduce the models it will require some kind of [Code Generation](http://www.mathworks.com/products/simulink-coder/) tool to convert into c code.

I can do this, but I was wondering if there was a better, more standard way to go about implementing a Hill-Type muscle model because the models presented there seemed overly complicated.

I wouldn't mind a description of how to implement one here as an answer, but a simple reading reference will also suffice.

Comment: Okay, I found a good place to start with: Reading the source code of [Millard 2012 Muscle Modules](http://simtk-confluence.stanford.edu:8080/display/OpenSim/Millard+2012+Muscle+Models)

Comment: If this reference helped to solve your question, would you summarizing it as an answer (and accepting it) to help other people with the same question?

Comment: Nah the source code only helps you get so far sadly. I'm still working on figuring this out

Comment: Did you ever find a solution above and beyond the Millard 2012 Muscle modules?

Comment: Kinda, I made https://github.com/Phylliida/openmuscle which I'm fairly certain is correct. Just really gross

Comment: Find the open source c++ implementation and more of the Geyer the model. [Dzelandini](https://bitbucket.org/efx/libnmm/src)